# how to get non-JTA-managed connection from DataSource

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, weblogic, jta

I'm using EJB 2 with container managed transactions (JTA) on WebLogic server. For debugging purposes, I'm trying to get `Connection` object from the `DataSource` retrieved from JNDI, execute an update and commit. However, I'm getting the following exception when trying to commit.

`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call commit when using distributed transactions`

The `DataSource` type I'm using is of type `weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource` and the `Connection` object is of type `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection-OracleDS-187`.

Clearly the `Connection` object I'm retrieving is trying to participate in JTA transaction, which is not what I want. How do I get non-JTA-managed connection from the `DataSource`?

Here is how I'm currently retrieving the connection

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    DataSource ds = ConnectionFactory.getDataSourceFromJNDI("jdbc/OracleDS");
    connection = ds.getConnection();
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(...);
    ps.setString(1, msg);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    connection.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    if (connection != null)
        connection.rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, use a non-XA jdbc driver for your connection pool.Second, call con.setAutoCommit(false) otherwise each sql statement will immediatly commited.

Comment: Changing the driver is not possibility

Comment: So you have no choice but leave the transaction manager handle your transactions

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin is right, as the container (bound to it's configuration) will manage transactions by design in a JTA setting.